# How to get NumberFormatter::parse() to only parse actual numeric strings?

Tags: php, number-formatting, string-parsing

I’m trying to parse some strings in some messed-up CSV files (about 100,000 rows per file). Some columns have been squished together in some rows, and I’m trying to get them unsquished back into their proper columns. Part of the logic needed there is to find whether a substring in a given colum is numeric or not.

Non-numeric strings can be anything, including strings that happen to begin with a number; numeric strings are generally written the European way, with dots used for thousand separators and commas for decimals, so without going through a bunch of string replacements, `is_numeric()` won’t do the trick:

```
\var_dump(is_numeric('3.527,25')); // bool(FALSE)
```

I thought – naïvely, it transpires – that the right thing to do would be to use `NumberFormatter::parse()`, but it seems that function doesn’t actually check whether the string given as a whole is parseable as a numeric string at all – instead it just starts at the beginning and when it reaches a character not allowed in a numeric string, cuts off the rest.

Essentially, what I’m looking for is something that will yield this:

```
$formatter = new \NumberFormatter('de-DE', \NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);
\var_dump($formatter->parse('3.527,25')); // float(3527.25)
\var_dump($formatter->parse('3thisisnotanumber')); // bool(FALSE)
```

But all I can get is this:

```
$formatter = new \NumberFormatter('de-DE', \NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);
\var_dump($formatter->parse('3.527,25')); // float(3527.25)
\var_dump($formatter->parse('3thisisnotanumber')); // float(3)
```

I figured perhaps the problem was that the `LENIENT_PARSE` attribute was set to true, but setting it to false (`$formatter->setAttribute(\NumberFormatter::LENIENT_PARSE, 0)`) has no effect; non-numeric strings still get parsed just fine as long as they begin with a number.

Since there are so many rows and each row may have as many as ten columns that need to be validated, I’m looking at upwards of a million validations per file – for that reason, I would prefer avoiding a `preg_match()`-based solution, since a million regex match calls would be quite expensive.

Is there some way to tell the `NumberFormatter` class that you would like it to please *not* be lenient and only treat the string as parseable if the *entire* string is numeric?

Comment: Given this, I would attempt to `parse()` then `format()` with the same `NumberFormatter` and see if the begin and end result are the same.

Comment: Do you at least have some idea which other characters appear in values you consider numeric? Would those only be dots and commas?

Comment: @El_Vanja Dots, commas and potentially a leading hyphen for negatives. Nothing else (no scientific notation or Es or anything like that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can strip all the separators and check if whatever remains is a numeric value.

```php
function customIsNumeric(string $value): bool
{
    return is_numeric(str_replace(['.', ','], '', $value));
}
```

Live test available [here](https://3v4l.org/UGVe9).

Comment: Ah yes, that should work. Do you know how it compares, speed-wise, to doing `if (preg_match("/[^0-9,.-]/", $value))`? I guess `str_replace()` would need to create a copy of the variable and check on that, so I wonder what the relative expense would be (actually, does `preg_match()` also create a copy?)…

Comment: I don't know about the inner workings, but having benchmarked them (trivially, through `microtime`) with 100k array values (only performing the `var_dump`s), they average about the same.

Comment: But, please take into consideration that operating on 100k values took a mere 0.2 seconds on average. So, whichever function you decide to use, it won't affect your script performance much. The bottleneck will be reading the file / writing back to it.

Answer (score -2):

You can use [is_numeric()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) to check that it is only numbers before parsing.  But NumberFormatter does not do what you are looking for here.

Comment: As I mention in the question, I _can’t_ use `is_numeric()` (at least not without manipulating the string first), since that will also return false on all the strings that are actually numeric.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet sorry about that what about `preg_match('#[^0-9\.,]#',$variable);`

Comment: That’s what I’m trying to avoid. `preg_match()` is slow, and would have to be run up to ten times per row on a file of 100,000 rows – that’s a million regex matches that I’d really like to be able to go without.